# change value of var in AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiapplicationdelegate

In my AppDelegate, I have

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomerProfile.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property   (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property   (strong, nonatomic) int x;

@end
```

At class B, I do

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate        =   [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.x   =   5;
```

Then at Class C, I do

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate        =   [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] delegate];
 appDelegate.x   =   4;
```

Eventually, at class D I print out the result of x and  **x = 5**. Should x be **4**. 
It is confusing me. Please advice me on this issue.
Thanks

Comment: for clarification, you initialize the classes in this order: class B - class C - class D ?

Comment: Include the code from Class D, and put log statements right before the assignment in B and C and the read in D so you can verify in which order order these statements run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your App delegate method your property x is set to strong (aka retain), you have to set to assign, a int var can't be retained because its not a object:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic, readwrite) int x; //then @synthesize in the implementation
```

Second, you have to import the header of your appDelegate (in your B,C,D Classes)

```
#import "yourAppDelegate.h"
```

set your appDelegate instance:

```
yourAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; // or [NSApplication sharedApplication] if your app it is for OS X
```

then set your x var to the desired value

```
appDelegate.x = 5 (or whatever)
```

I tested this in one of my projects and works.

Comment: after changing the value of x to 4 in C and you are getting new C of 4 in D. is it what you meant? I coul set the value of x however.Then I changed the value of x,  and I still get the oldest value ( in this case is 5 )

Comment: I fixed the code in my answer, i forgot to write the x value: appDelegate.x = 5 . In my test I set the x value in several of my classes and then log the value of x NSLog(@"%d",appDelegate.x), i get the new value seted and not the old one like you.

Comment: yeah you are rite, i made a change i got what I want..Thanks